# Chrome randomly does not load localhost

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, pageload, internet-connection

I've been using Chrome to work on my localhost for a while now.
Since a Chrome update (Version 107.0.5304.110 (Official Build) (arm64)) without even switching projects, sometimes it loads without problems and sometimes I get a "No Internet connection" error.
And if I click on the information icon, to your left in the url bar, it shows: "localhost:8888 Connection is not secure".

If I use Firefox for the same thing, everything works fine.

Can anyone give me a clue what's going on? What can I do to fix it?

I'm using Apple M1 Pro with Ventura 13

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is chromium [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42058)

basically using `--enable-ipv6` flag should fix your issue
but many people still have this issue
I have no idea why they still have this bug. It dates back to 2010

many people have this bug have in common

- use unix based OS
- use chromium or chrome

I would suggest just use the flag. But if this issue persists after updates
there can be multiple reasons for it

mainly if your network configuration is messed up. Try `127.0.0.1:8888`. See if you network configuration is like [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration#localhost_is_resolved_over_the_network)

on the other hand the issue may be with the browser itself. Look at the 3 links below

basically I looked through them and many people who have the same issue  never found a fix

most of them just used the ipv6 flag or other browsers

you can follow this [guide](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/localhost-refused-to-connect)

[bug report 1](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8910)

[bug report 2](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42058)

[bug report 3](https://%20https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32522)